# Entity Framework - No option to view tables

Tags: entity-framework

[image]

I have an issue with EF 6. My database already has tables, so I'm not using code-first.

In the data connections, I can expand tables and see everything.

When I try `update model from database` and add the tables, I have no option.

Usually the tables has a tree view, but there isn't one. If I open the refresh tab, I can see the tables.

I cannot even check the tables check box in the Update wizard

After I click OK, I see an empty entity data model designer.

When I expand the database in Data Connections, it connects. As soon as I try via the entity data model designer, the database in the DataConnections shows as offline...

I then deleted the .edmx file and all associated files. I then re-added, re-created a new connection string etc with a new Entities name. It works fine for a while. I can't clarify what for a while means. It may be after I try to update the .edmx file (via the wizard) a few times it begins to fail.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

In Database first if updating from the database and If tables are already showing under the refresh tab that means EF Edmx already has it. Delete models from EF Edmx file, save the file and it should ask you run the custom tool, which you need to and and try updating from database again. Good idea would to make copies of the first :)

Comment: I know its not code first but database first thats why you need to delete models from edmx and run the t4 template then and try again by update from database again

Comment: Sorry, do you mean delete them from within the the .tt file  tree view (in Visual Studio)

Comment: open up your edmx file in designer view...you do have that right??

Comment: Yes. It is empty!

Comment: hmm...do you see them poco classes files when you expand the .tt file?

Comment: Yes, they are there under the .tt file

Comment: ok then delete those and try again. I mean only the poco classes not the tt file itself

Comment: Did that - same issue. Oddly, in the Data Connections, when I double click on a table it's failing.. I get the error `Could not retrieve the definition of [dbo].[Stageplan] from the server`

Comment: hmm...does this table have a primary key as id

Comment: Yes, I had checked that. All 3 of my tables do, all with Identity specification set to true as well!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130853/discussion-between-glant-and-mydaftquestions).